# Is DeprovisionScope necessary before DeprovisionStore?

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I would like to Deprovision everything in the database.

When I test it, [DeprovisionStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserver.sqlsyncscopedeprovisioning.deprovisionstore.aspx) method itself clears everything including - tables, triggers, stored procedures and templates.

However, in this [Synchronize SQL Server and SQL Azure using Sync Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zkap/archive/2012/04/12/synchronize-sql-server-and-sql-azure-using-sync-framework.aspx) article, DeprovisionScope is used before DeprovisionStore.

```
onPremiseSqlDepro.DeprovisionScope("product");
onPremiseSqlDepro.DeprovisionStore();
```

Is DeprovisionScope really necessary before DeprovisionStore?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not required.

If you want to completely deprovision the entire database, just call DeprovisionStore directly.

DeprovisionScope and DeprovisionTemplate is used if you want to deprovision specific scopes or templates only and leaving other scopes/templates as it is.